# Send Bitcoin payments to any bank via API

Tags: api, banks

I am looking into paying our overseas suppliers via bitcoin to speed up the process of settling invoices. The issue is that I don't want them to have to deal with bitcoin themselves.

My question is - is there an API available that I can use to build my app that will allow me to deposit BTC to any bank account number that I choose?

Thanks!

Comment: If there were, we wouldn't need Bitcoin.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz or it would mean that the banks have incorporated Bitcoin completely into their accounts.

Answer (score 3):

The closest solution to this is setting up your supplier with a payments processor like Coinbase or Bitpay, who will convert your BTC to fiat instantly. However, there's no way to send BTC to a bank account directly without some action by the other party.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bitpay to do it. What you can do is create a bitpay account and input their bank details to send the money to. Then you can send the amount for a transaction to the account related with that account and it will be transferred to their account.